# Qt Table and Tree View with the same model

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt

I have a neat Model based off QAbstractItemModel. This has a simple hierarchical tree structure which works perfectly for QTreeView. However, I want the QTableView/QListView to access and display only the leaf nodes( ALL leaf nodes ). What is the best way to do this? I don't want to rebuild the model( because it will be expensive ) and I do not want to have two models( same reason ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a proxy model. A class that sits between the View and the Model and filters out all of the non-leaf nodes and then just forwards the function calls to the original model for the leaves.

Comment: @LászlóPapp I was thinking in more generic terms, not QSortFilterProxyModel specifically like writing my own proxy.  But the sugested qtdeclarative/src/qmlmodels/qqmltreemodeltotablemodel.cpp seems to solve this issue, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need these steps to achieve this:

1. Flatten a tree model into a list or table model.
2. Remove the rows having children.
3. Sort the list.

So, you could just wrap this flattening model inside a `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

`QFlattenProxyModel` is work in progress to be included in Qt:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-117716